# How do I root Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro (MK16a/i)?

Tags: rooting

I am kind of new to Android and smartphones.

```
Phone: Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro
Model number: MK16a
Android version: 2.3.4
```

So far, I have been able to find the following sources:

- I first saw [this XDA-Developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1286885). It seems relatively complicated. (And I haven't had much experience with the Linux shell either, so I shy away from this...)
- The previous thread linked to [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1319653), which was 'easier'.

  - However, reading the instructions, I need ADB drivers or something. No clue how to get these.
  - Also, avast has blocked parts of the file from downloading. (Zerg rush...?) I can disable avast's web shield temporarily, if you guys recommend this method.
- [This article](http://www.freeyourandroid.com/guide/root-xperia-pro-gingerbread) which mentions a thread similar to the previous one.
- [Android Forums - Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro: All Things Root Guide](http://androidforums.com/xperia-pro-all-things-root/481398-sony-ericsson-xperia-pro-all-things-root-guide.html).

I would rather do this using as foolproof, easy, and unlikely-to-brick method as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable `USB debugging` from `Settings->Applications->Development`.
2. Install [*SuperOneClick*](http://shortfuse.org/) on your PC.
3. Connect the phone to the PC via USB.
4. Run *SuperOneClick* and click `Root`.